# In R, when creating a model, is there an equivalent to the by statement in SAS?

Tags: r

Say I have a data set that I'd like to create a lm, for each combination of variable A and B. Where A has two values: 'a' and 'b', and B has three values: 1,2,3. This leaving me with six possible combinations of variables A and B.

This said, I would like to create six (6) models. In example the first model would have the data subsetted where A = a and B = 1.

In SAS, in example, the code would be as follows (please note the by statement):

```
proc glm data = mydate;
by A B;
class Cat1 Cat2;
model Y = X + Cat1 + Cat2;
run;
```

The by statement will generate one model for combination of A and B.

Comment: you can use the `interaction` command to create a factor variable that has all the combinations of `A` and `B`. e.g. with `data(mtcars)`, `interaction(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$carb)` , you can then use `split` to divide your data into groups based on this new variable https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html, and then use lapply to apply `lm` to the resulting list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `group_by` in the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package will run an analysis for each subgroup combination.  Using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  do(mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = .))

res$mod
```

Will give you the list of `lm` objects.

Other packages will make this more elegant.  You could do this in-line with  the [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package and go straight to the list of `lm` objects:

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  do(mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = .)) %>%
  use_series(mod)
```

Or use the [broom](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) package to extract coefficient values from the `lm` objects:

```
library(broom)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  do(mod = lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = .)) %>%
  glance(mod)

Source: local data frame [4 x 13]
Groups: am, gear

  am gear r.squared adj.r.squared     sigma statistic    p.value df     logLik      AIC      BIC  deviance df.residual
1  0    3 0.6223489     0.5594070 2.2379851  9.887679 0.00290098  3 -31.694140 71.38828 74.22048 60.102926          12
2  0    4 0.9653343     0.8960028 0.9899495 13.923469 0.18618733  3  -2.862760 13.72552 11.27070  0.980000           1
3  1    4 0.7849464     0.6989249 2.9709337  9.125006 0.02144702  3 -18.182504 44.36501 44.68277 44.132234           5
4  1    5 0.9827679     0.9655358 1.2362092 57.031169 0.01723212  3  -5.864214 19.72843 18.16618  3.056426           2
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! They all work. However, I am going the dplyr route.

Comment: @Illya I'm glad it answered your question. If you click the checkmark next to an answer to accept it, it will indicate that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

This is really just a split-apply step:

1. split the data into chunks

   ```
   smydate <- split(mydate, list(A = A, B = B))
   ```

   Each component of `smydate` represents the data for a particular combination of `A` and `B`. You may need to add `drop = TRUE` to the `split` call if your data doesn't have all combinations of the levels of `A` and `B`.
2. apply the `lm()` function over the components of the list `smydate`

   ```
   lmFun <- function(dat) {
     lm(y ~ x + cat1 + cat2, data = dat)
   }
   models <- lapply(smydate, lmFun)
   ```

Now you have a list, `models`, where each component contains a `lm` object for the particular combination of `A` and `B`.

An example (based on the one shown by `rawr` in the comments is:

```
models <- lapply(split(mtcars, list(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear), drop = TRUE),
                 function(x) {lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x)})
str(models)
models
```

which gives:

```
> str(models, max = 1)
List of 4
 $ 0.3:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ 0.4:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ 1.4:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ 1.5:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
> models
$`0.3`

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         disp  
  27.994610    -2.384834    -0.007983  


$`0.4`

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         disp  
   219.1047    -106.8075       0.9953  


$`1.4`

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         disp  
   43.27860     -3.03114     -0.09481  


$`1.5`

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         disp  
  41.779042    -7.230952    -0.006731
```

As `rawr` notes in the comments, you can do this in fewer steps using `by()`, or any one of a number of other higher-level functions in say the **plyr** package, but doing things by hand at least once illustrates the generality of the approach; you can always use the short cuts once you are familiar with the general idea.

Comment: or just `models <- by(mtcars, mtcars$gear, function(x) lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, data = x))`

Comment: Well, yes, you can skin this particular cat (sorry RCatLadies) in all manner of ways. I personally am not a fan of `by` and the way it generates output. I wanted to show a very general way of approaching these problems, but yes, there are also shortcuts.

Comment: or `lapply(smydate,lm,formula=y~x+cat1+cat2)` (since `lm` takes `data` as its second argument and will correctly use the elements of `smydate` for that purpose if you specify its first argument `formula`)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes and I considered showing just that but decided against it as it was a little less general (sometimes you do just need an function) but I'm glad you brought that up here in the comments as that is how I would have done this specific example myself.

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, you can use `lmList` to fit linear models to categories, after using @bjoseph's strategy of generating an interaction variable:

```
mydate <- transform(mydate, ABcat=interaction(A,B,drop=TRUE))
library("lme4")  ## or library("nlme")
lmList(Y~X+Cat1+Cat2|ABcat,mydate)
```

Comment: +1 Same problem as with my `split` approach, but important to set `drop = TRUE` in the `interaction` call if you don't have observations for all combinations of the factors as `interaction()` and `split()` form levels for all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You could try several different things.

Let's say our data is:

```
structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4), y = c(2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("A", "B", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
x
#>   A B x y
   1 A A 1 2
   2 A B 2 2
   3 B A 3 2
   4 B B 4 2
```

**by()**

This returns a list-type object.  Notice that it doesn't return results in the order we might have expected.  It's trying to keep the second factor as stable as possible when iterating.  You could adjust this by using `list(x$B,x$A)`

```
by(x[c("x","y")],list(x$A,x$B),function(x){x[1]*x[2]})
[1] 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[1] 6
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[1] 4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[1] 8
```

**expand.grid()**

This is a simple for loop where we pre-generated the combinations of interest, subset the data in the loop and perform the function of interest.  `expand.grid()` can be slow with large sets of combinations and for loops aren't necessarily fast but you have a lot of control in the middle.

```
combinations = expand.grid(levels(x$A),levels(x$B))
for(i in 1:nrow(combinations)){
  d = x[x$A==combinations[i,1] & x$B==combinations[i,2],c("x","y")]
  print(d[1]*d[2])
}
#>   x
   1 2
     x
   3 6
     x
   2 4
     x
   4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fit/predictions instead of summary stats(t-tests, etc), it's easier to fit an interaction model of `Y~(A:B)*(X + Cat1 + Cat2) - 1 - X - Cat1 - Cat2`; by subtracting out the main effects, R will reparameterize and place all the variance on the interactions. Here's an example:

```
> mtcars <- within(mtcars, {cyl = as.factor(cyl); am=as.factor(am)})
> model <- lm(mpg~(cyl:am)*(hp+wt)-1-hp-wt, mtcars)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ (cyl:am) * (hp + wt) - 1 - hp - wt, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6685 -0.9071  0.0000  0.7705  4.1879 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
cyl4:am0     2.165e+01  2.252e+01   0.961   0.3517    
cyl6:am0     6.340e+01  4.245e+01   1.494   0.1560    
cyl8:am0     2.746e+01  5.000e+00   5.492 6.20e-05 ***
cyl4:am1     4.725e+01  5.144e+00   9.184 1.51e-07 ***
cyl6:am1     2.320e+01  3.808e+01   0.609   0.5515    
cyl8:am1     1.877e+01  1.501e+01   1.251   0.2302    
cyl4:am0:hp -4.635e-02  1.107e-01  -0.419   0.6815    
cyl6:am0:hp  7.425e-03  1.650e-01   0.045   0.9647    
cyl8:am0:hp -2.110e-02  2.531e-02  -0.834   0.4175    
cyl4:am1:hp -7.288e-02  4.457e-02  -1.635   0.1228    
cyl6:am1:hp -2.000e-02  4.733e-02  -0.423   0.6786    
cyl8:am1:hp -1.127e-02  4.977e-02  -0.226   0.8240    
cyl4:am0:wt  1.762e+00  5.341e+00   0.330   0.7460    
cyl6:am0:wt -1.332e+01  1.303e+01  -1.022   0.3231    
cyl8:am0:wt -2.025e+00  1.099e+00  -1.843   0.0851 .  
cyl4:am1:wt -6.465e+00  2.467e+00  -2.621   0.0193 *  
cyl6:am1:wt -4.926e-15  1.386e+01   0.000   1.0000    
cyl8:am1:wt         NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.499 on 15 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9933,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9858 
F-statistic: 131.4 on 17 and 15 DF,  p-value: 3.045e-13
```

compare with a cyl4:am1 submodel:

```
> summary(lm(mpg~wt+hp, mtcars, subset=cyl=='4' & am=='1'))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp, data = mtcars, subset = cyl == "4" & 
    am == "1")

Residuals:
    Datsun 710       Fiat 128    Honda Civic Toyota Corolla      Fiat X1-9  Porsche 914-2 
      -2.66851        4.18787       -2.61455        3.25523       -2.62538       -0.77799 
  Lotus Europa     Volvo 142E 
       1.17181        0.07154 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 47.24552    6.57304   7.188 0.000811 ***
wt          -6.46508    3.15205  -2.051 0.095512 .  
hp          -0.07288    0.05695  -1.280 0.256814    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.193 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6378,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.493 
F-statistic: 4.403 on 2 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.07893
```

The estimates of the coefficients are *exactly* the same, and the standard errors are higher/more conservative here, because *s* is being estimated only from the subset rather than pooling across all the models. Pooling may or may not be an appropriate assumption for your use case, statistically.

It's also much easier to get predictions: `predict(model, X)` vs having to split-apply-combine again.